# Overriding a blaze template

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am using [autoform-ionic](https://github.com/meteoric/autoform-ionic). I wanted to add an option to disable adding and removing from arrays on a `afArrayField`.

I use `quickField` which references `afArrayField_ionic`. I created a template with the same name in order to (hopefully) override it so I could add some of my own logic.

```
template(name="afArrayField_ionic")
  // my custom code here
```

However, this gives me an error saying that there cannot be two templates with the same name.

How would one override a template to replace it with a different one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension